# LASSO and duality theorem

Tags: optimization, lasso, regularization, constrained-optimization, duality

I am confused with Lagrange duality theorem. Let us consider the problem

$$
\hat{\beta}  = \underset{\beta \in \mathbb{R}^{n}}{\arg \min} \left[\sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_{i} - \beta_{i})^{2} + \lambda \sum_{i=1}^{k} |\beta_{i}|\right].
$$

Is it always true that for any given $\lambda > 0$ there exist some $s(y,\lambda_{j})$ such that

$$
\hat{\beta}  = \underset{\beta \in \mathbb{R}^{n}}{\arg \min} \sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_{i} - \beta_{i})^{2},
$$
subject to
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{k} |\beta_{i}| \leq s.
$$

Note, I understand that the opposite is correct i.e. for a given $s$ there exists $\lambda$, it is duality theorem.